# Is there a way to specify first-day-of-week for Vuetify Date picker globally?

Tags: datepicker, vuetify.js

Is there a way to specify first-day-of-week for Vuetify Date picker globally?
I don't want to specify the props on each separately.

Answer (score 6):

#### No, there isn't a way to do  that

You have to use the widget as per documentation (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers) with the `first-day-of-week` property.

```html
<v-date-picker
  v-model="picker"
  :first-day-of-week="1"
></v-date-picker>
```

if you look into code, you'll notice that the param default is 0, so there's no magical global setting for this.

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VDatePicker/VDatePicker.ts#L64

Comment: I believe you didn't read my question carefully. I don't want to specify it every time since across the application it is used numerous times. 

Vuetify has config, which supports changing global settings during the initialization, however, changing the first day of the week is not one of them.

I'm searching for a workaround that would set the default value of the v-date-picker from 0 to 1 so it always starts on Monday.

Imagine setting this props on 80 calendars, it would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

As for few other components' defaults, you can simply wrap it in new component (let's call it `MyDatePicker`) and use that one across the application instead.

To harness all event handlers intended for Vuetify component `VDatePicker` upon your custom `MyDatePicker`, you'll need to add `v-on="$listeners"`.